# Setting up py_func op after importing GraphDef in TensorFlow

Tags: python, tensorflow

I have a saved graph definition, which is imported with `tf.train.import_meta_graph`. The graph containes `py_func` op, which is not serializable. Can I define and assign python function to this op without building a graph from scratch?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is possible, but may be a bit fragile. In particular, the pyfuncs need to be re-defined in the same order that they were defined in the original graph (so that they have the same identifier in the [FuncRegistry](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/python/ops/script_ops.py#L36)).

An example. We can define a graph that includes a py_func:

```
import tensorflow as tf

def my_py_func(x):
  return 13. * x + 2.

def train_model():
  with tf.Graph().as_default():
    some_input = tf.constant([[1., 2., 3., 4.],
                              [5., 6., 7., 8.]])
    after_py_func = tf.py_func(my_py_func, [some_input], Tout=tf.float32,
                               name="my_py_func")
    coefficient = tf.get_variable(
        "coefficient",
        shape=[])
    bias = tf.get_variable(
        "bias",
        shape=[])
    loss = tf.reduce_sum((coefficient * some_input + bias - after_py_func) ** 2)
    global_step = tf.contrib.framework.get_or_create_global_step()
    train_op = tf.group(tf.train.AdamOptimizer(0.1).minimize(loss),
                        tf.assign_add(global_step, 1))
    # Make it easy to retreive things we care about when the metagraph is reloaded.
    tf.add_to_collection('useful_ops', bias)
    tf.add_to_collection('useful_ops', coefficient)
    tf.add_to_collection('useful_ops', loss)
    tf.add_to_collection('useful_ops', train_op)
    tf.add_to_collection('useful_ops', global_step)
    tf.add_to_collection('useful_ops', some_input)
    init_op = tf.global_variables_initializer()
    saver = tf.train.Saver()
    with tf.Session() as session:
      session.run(init_op)
      for i in range(5000):
        (_, evaled_loss, evaled_coefficient, evaled_bias,
         evaled_global_step) = session.run(
             [train_op, loss, coefficient, bias, global_step])
        if i % 1000 == 0:
          print(evaled_global_step, evaled_loss, evaled_coefficient,
                evaled_bias)
      saver.save(session, "./trained_pyfunc_model", global_step=global_step)
```

This does some basic training (matching the linear function found in the py_func):

```
1 37350.4 -0.0934748 0.193026
1001 19.2717 12.3749 5.40368
2001 0.108373 12.9532 2.2548
3001 8.28227e-06 12.9996 2.00222
4001 3.77258e-09 13.0 2.00004
```

If we then, in a new Python session, try to load the metagraph without re-defining the pyfunc, we get an error:

```
def load_model():
  with tf.Graph().as_default():
    saver = tf.train.import_meta_graph("./trained_pyfunc_model-5000.meta")
    bias, coefficient, loss, train_op, global_step, some_input = tf.get_collection('useful_ops')
    #after_py_func = tf.py_func(my_py_func, [some_input], Tout=tf.float32,
    #                           name="my_py_func")
    with tf.Session() as session:
      saver.restore(session, "./trained_pyfunc_model-5000")
      (_, evaled_loss, evaled_coefficient, evaled_bias,
       evaled_global_step) = session.run(
           [train_op, loss, coefficient, bias, global_step])
      print("Restored: ", evaled_global_step, evaled_loss, evaled_coefficient, evaled_bias)
```

> UnknownError (see above for traceback): KeyError: 'pyfunc_0'

However, as long as the py_funcs are defined in the same order and have the same implementation, we should be fine:

```
def load_model():
  with tf.Graph().as_default():
    saver = tf.train.import_meta_graph("./trained_pyfunc_model-5000.meta")
    bias, coefficient, loss, train_op, global_step, some_input = tf.get_collection('useful_ops')
    after_py_func = tf.py_func(my_py_func, [some_input], Tout=tf.float32,
                               name="my_py_func")
    with tf.Session() as session:
      saver.restore(session, "./trained_pyfunc_model-5000")
      (_, evaled_loss, evaled_coefficient, evaled_bias,
       evaled_global_step) = session.run(
           [train_op, loss, coefficient, bias, global_step])
      print("Restored: ", evaled_global_step, evaled_loss, evaled_coefficient, evaled_bias)
```

This lets us continue training, or whatever else we'd like to do with the restored model:

```
Restored:  5001 1.77897e-09 13.0 2.00003
```

Note that stateful py_funcs will be harder to deal with: TensorFlow is not saving any of the Python variables that may be associated with them!